# Using a database as a custom file type

Tags: sql-server-express

SQL Server 2008 Express has the ability to use attached files as the data source for a database. The limit on the database size is 10gb. I want to create a custom file type that will masquerade as a database file (i.e. the extension is something other than .mdf). My problem is the LDF file. Is it possible to use the .mdf file without using the LDF?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: SQLlight doesn't seem to support entity framework.